# Adding a HTTP header to the Angular HttpClient doesn't send the header, why?

Tags: angular, http-headers, angular-httpclient

Here is my code:

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

---

```js
logIn(username: string, password: string) {
    const url = 'http://server.com/index.php';
    const body = JSON.stringify({username: username,
                                 password: password});
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    this.http.post(url, body, {headers: headers}).subscribe(
        (data) => {
            console.log(data);
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (err.error instanceof Error) {
                console.log('Client-side error occured.');
            } else {
                console.log('Server-side error occured.');
            }
        }
    );
}
```

and here the network debug:

```
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:46
Content-Type:text/plain
```

and Data are stored in 'Request Payload' but in my server doesn't received the POST values:

```
print_r($_POST);
Array
(
)
```

I believe the error comes from the header not set during the POST, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Yes, thanks! But after not receiving data on my Back-end, I went to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Anyway the main question is anserwerd

Answer (score 422, accepted):

The instances of the new `HttpHeader` class are **immutable** objects. Invoking class methods will return a new instance as result. So basically, you need to do the following:

```js
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

or

```js
const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
```

**Update: adding multiple headers**

```js
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('h1', 'v1').set('h2','v2');
```

or

```js
const headers = new HttpHeaders({'h1':'v1','h2':'v2'});
```

**Update: accept object map for HttpClient headers & params**

Since [5.0.0-beta.6](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/18490) is now possible to skip the creation of a `HttpHeaders` object an directly pass an object map as argument. So now its possible to do the following:

```
http.get('someurl',{
   headers: {'header1':'value1','header2':'value2'}
});
```

Comment: Interesting. So, for us coming from OO world, `set` method name is somewhat misleading.

Comment: What if I want to set multiple headers? I've tried to chain the comment `HttpHeaders().set(..).set(..)` but now again the headers are not getting written to the HTTP header fields?!

Comment: It should work fine according to the src https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/headers.ts . I cant help you any further without more information about your issue (code)

Comment: So in my case I made an mistake by switching headers & params in the list of arguments to a function (since both accepted a json object). Meaning just watch out for mistakes, and HttpHeaders as type is a good practice after all.. Off-topic: when you can use objects everywhere, don't use TypeScript but VanillaJS.

Comment: Why have headers and requests been made immutable?
https://angular.io/guide/http#immutability

Comment: I am using Angular 6. After setting headers also, I am getting `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
properties.component.ts:23 GOT ERROR:-` on console. Can someone please suggest any solution?

Comment: I have already tried many methods. Changed the syntaxes of **HttpHeaders** values. Also checked angular.io. I am able to make API call and get the response if there is no AUTH. I am getting the above error in case of BASIC authentication.

Comment: As an important update, as of Angular 6.1.7, you cant use `.set()` either

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Its still part of the public API https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders#set

Comment: @Jota.Toledo so is `.append()` but they only work when chained. `new HttpDeaders().set()` works but `let header = new HttpHeaders(); header.set()` doesnt

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Both append and set return new instances with the changes applied, as I explain in my answer. How is that related to your previous comment? I think you should remove your comment, as you are making an incorrect assertion.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo i wont remove my comment as it will help others, you either need to pass the headers into the HttpHeader constructor or call `.set()` or `.append()` directly from the `new HttpHeader()`

Comment: lol thats exactly what I described in my answer. Whatever, just notice that "as of 6.1.7, you cant uset .set()" is an wrong assertion, or poorly explained.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo ill rephrase, you cant use `.set()` and `.append()` without it being direct onto the constructor method

Comment: Silly to make it not behave like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/append

Comment: option 
_const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'});_ 
doesn't work, at least on Angular 9

my implementation : 
`let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','text/xml;charset=UTF-8').set...`

Answer (score 32):

To add multiples params or headers you can do the following:

```js
constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

//....

const url = `${environment.APP_API}/api/request`;

let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('header1', hvalue1); // create header object
headers = headers.append('header2', hvalue2); // add a new header, creating a new object
headers = headers.append('header3', hvalue3); // add another header

let params = new HttpParams().set('param1', value1); // create params object
params = params.append('param2', value2); // add a new param, creating a new object
params = params.append('param3', value3); // add another param 

return this._http.get<any[]>(url, { headers: headers, params: params })
```

Comment: This method does not seem to work either. I mean, you can add the headers, and they will show in the `lazyUpdate` property, but eventually it will crash with the `CreateListFromArrayLike` exception when making the request effective by subscribing to it.

Comment: To add multiple headers use: headers:HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    'Application-Id': this.appId,
    "REST-API-Key": this.apiKey,
     "Content-Type": "application/json"
  });

Answer (score 16):

set http headers like below in your http request

```
return this.http.get(url, { headers: new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token})
 });
```

Answer (score 10):

I struggled with this for a long time. I am using Angular 6 and I found that

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('key', 'value');
```

did not work. But what did work was

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().append('key', 'value');
```

did, which makes sense when you realize they are immutable. So having created a header you can't add to it. I haven't tried it, but I suspect

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
let headers1 = headers.append('key', 'value');
```

would work too.

Comment: Your first attempt should work, you're assigning the result of the append to the headers variable. Right now your explanation doesn't make any sense, specially your last guess that adding a `let` *may* fix it

Answer (score 8):

I was with Angular 8 and the only thing which worked for me was this:

```
  getCustomHeaders(): HttpHeaders {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .set('Api-Key', 'xxx');
    return headers;
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

In the manual (https://angular.io/guide/http) I read:
The HttpHeaders class is immutable, so every set() returns a new instance and applies the changes.

The following code works for me with angular-4:

```
 return this.http.get(url, {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('UserEmail', email ) });
```

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to add HttpHeaders with HttpClient

```
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders  } from '@angular/common/http';
```

your constructor should be like this.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

then you can use like this

```
   let header = new HttpHeaders({ "Authorization": "Bearer "+token});

   const requestOptions = {  headers: header};                                                                                                                                                                            

    return this.http.get<any>(url, requestOptions)
        .toPromise()
        .then(data=> {
            //...
            return data;
    });
```

Comment: how you get the token?

Answer (score 0):

In my legacy app Array.from of prototype js was conflicting with angular's Array.from that was causing this problem. I resolved it by saving angular's Array.from version and reassigning it after prototype load.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this as well. I used an interceptor, it captures the response headers, then clone the headers(since headers are immutable objects) and then sends the modified headers. https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Answer (score -2):

**Angular 8** **HttpClient** Service example with **Error Handling** and **Custom Header**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Student } from '../model/student';
    import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
    import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ApiService {

      // API path
      base_path = 'http://localhost:3000/students';

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      // Http Options
      httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
      }

      // Handle API errors
      handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
          // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
          console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
        } else {
          // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
          // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
          console.error(
            `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
            `body was: ${error.error}`);
        }
        // return an observable with a user-facing error message
        return throwError(
          'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
      };


      // Create a new item
      createItem(item): Observable<Student> {
        return this.http
          .post<Student>(this.base_path, JSON.stringify(item), this.httpOptions)
          .pipe(
            retry(2),
            catchError(this.handleError)
          )
      }

      ....
      ....
```

[image]

Check complete example tutorial [here](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-7-8-httpclient-service-tutorial-to-consume-restfull-api-from-server/)

Comment: Is it me or is this kinda overkill for the question asked?

Comment: This isn't attempting to answer OPs question. Its just a bunch of code with no explanation whatsoever.

Comment: This is not even close to context. It looks like self-promotion.