# Angular 4.3 Httpclient doesn't send content type header

Tags: angular

How I can set the httpheaders, I add this code

```
  public post (servicio: string, item: any): Observable<any> 
  {
    const url = `${SERVER_URL}${servicio}`;   
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
    return this.http.post(url, item, {headers: headers})
     .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
     .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

In the chrome or fiddler the request is

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:56962
Origin:http://evil.com/
Referer:http://localhost:4200/entidad
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

Comment: what s the type of this.http? HttpClient?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular \[4.3\] Httpclient doesn't send header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286764/angular-4-3-httpclient-doesnt-send-header)

Answer (score 0):

Finally works isn't in the headers, in the asp.net core cors I add the following

```
  app.UseCors(builder =>
              builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .AllowAnyMethod());
            app.UseMvc();
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a go doing this:

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
```