# HttpClient Autherization Header not sent in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, httpclient

I am trying to send Autherization header with httpClient, But It is not sending in request .

```
getAuthorizationHeaderClient() {
    var jwt = this._cookie.get('my_authentication');        
    this.authHeader = new HttpHeaders();
    if (jwt) {
        this.authHeader.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwt);
    }
    return this.authHeader;
}

const req = new HttpRequest('POST',baseUrl + url, itemToPost,{    
    headers:this.getAuthorizationHeaderClient(),
    reportProgress: true,
});

this._httpClient.request(req).subscribe(event => {
    // Via this API, you get access to the raw event stream.
    // Look for upload progress events.
    if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
        // This is an upload progress event. Compute and show the % done:
        const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        console.log(`File is ${percentDone}% uploaded.`);
    } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        console.log('File is completely uploaded!');
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular \[4.3\] Httpclient doesn't send header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286764/angular-4-3-httpclient-doesnt-send-header)

Comment: How does the _httpClient create the request

Comment: @QuentinLaillé I have checked that question, but that question accepted answer is not working here

Comment: @MarcusH This code is taken from angular documantation

Comment: Can you show us the request in your browser's console please ?

Comment: @QuentinLaillé Updated question

Comment: I noticed 'jwt' in there, are you by any chances trying to impletement Auth0 in your webapp ? If so there's a complete tutorial on their website, if not there's still [angular-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt) which takes care of the headers when correctly setup'd, and you dont have to take care of that.

Comment: @QuentinLaillé thanks but angular-jwt is for angular 1 , i am working on angular 4

Comment: Whooops wrong link, here's [angular2-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt)

Comment: thanks for your help @QuentinLaillé

Comment: Keep us in touch with your future answer, it may help future users.