# Angular 4 Setting Headers with HttpClient Module

Tags: angular, header, httpclient

im new with Angular and i'm working on a project that for some reasons i have to set headers for server side authorization, Im using Angular 4 and the HttpClient Module imported from '@angular/common/http'

This is my AuthService Class

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../models/user';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest } from 
'@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Globals } from '../../utils/global';
import { Converters } from '../../utils/converters';


@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
getUserByToken(token: string): any {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);

    console.log(headers);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(this.global.urls['info'], { headers: headers }).subscribe((data) => {
        if (data != null) {
          this.converter.userJsonToObject(data).then((data: User) => {
            this.setCurrentUser(data);
            this.persistToken(data.token);
            resolve(data);
          });
        } else {
          reject('This user is not defined');
        }
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
    });

  }
```

[image: ARC]

When i run my project and i call getUserByToken(token) function, the server console told me that no token was send. 
The endpoint is working perfect with ARC so the issue is on the client side.
does anyone can help me to resolve this issue problem.
:D

Comment: You are having a typo in the `authorization` in which `A` should in be upper case. Also try to use `headers.set()` instead of `append`

Comment: by looking at my screenshot the endpoint is working fine even by taping 'authorization' anyway the issue is with the way that i'm setting the headers.
even by using header.set(), still not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular \[4.3\] Httpclient doesn't send header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286764/angular-4-3-httpclient-doesnt-send-header)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is of type  `immutable Map` so if you assign a new value it will reinitialize the object so you should be doing as

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                               .set('authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
```

or

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers = headers.set('authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
```

Comment: Thanks dude, this solved my problem,  as you mentioned HttpHeaders is immutable so i should put headers on constructor.