# HttpHeader isn't correctly sent

Tags: angular, http-headers, angular-httpclient

I am coding according to this guide: https://angular.io/guide/http#configuring-other-parts-of-the-request.

My code is the following:

```
loadMenuOptions(): void {
    console.log('this.currentApiKey |' + this.currentApiKey);
     let header = new HttpHeaders();
    header = header.set('api-key', this.currentApiKey);

    this.commonService. getMenuOptions(MENU_OPTIONS, header).subscribe(respuesta => this.setMenuOptions(respuesta));
  }
```

The following code is when I send this object to the server:

```
getMenuOptions(endPoint: string, header: HttpHeaders): Observable<OptionsResponse> {
    console.log('header:' + JSON.stringify(header));
    return this.http.get<OptionsResponse>(endPoint,  header)
      .pipe(
        tap(res => this.log('getMenuOptions | status | ' + res.header.status)),
        catchError(this.handleError('getMenuOptions', null)));
  }
```

> **JSON.stringify** shows this value: 
>   
>   header:{"normalizedNames":[],"lazyUpdate":[{"name":"api-key","value":"JEFE_HHHABBBJJJXXX","op":"s"}],"headers":[],"lazyInit":{"normalizedNames":[],"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":[]}}

but the server is not receiving the 'api-key' value.

I executed POSTMAN with the same value and the server correctly received the 'api-key' value.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

This snapshot represents the first time that is invoked the 'getMenuOptions' method: [first call to the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khopx.png)

This screenshot belongs to the second call to the server:

1. [1st part of the 2nd call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aks07.png)
2. [2nd part of the 2nd call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnUZv.png)

As you are seeing at the 2nd part of the 2nd call, the header which contains the 'api-key' value is sent inside a 'lazyUpdate' object.

Comment: `HttpHeaders` are immutable objects so you must refer to this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47724737/angular-4-setting-headers-with-httpclient-module/47724949#47724949)

Comment: @Aravind, if you see my code you will see that I create a new header object.

Comment: Could you add the request/response headers logged in the network devtools of a browser?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, I updated my post. :)

Comment: Please add your source code into your question, not pictures of it

Comment: @Jota.Toledo , I replaced pictures by the code.

Comment: My issue was solved. 

The problem was a misconfiguration in the server: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Thanks for all for your comments and time trying to solve my issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the implementation of your `getMenuOptions` method.
Your are not  respecting the definition of the `post` method from the `HttpClient`.

It should be like this:

```
http
  .post('/api/items/add', body, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token'),
  }).
```

Where:

```
1st argument: endpoint
2nd: request body
3rd: an object with the request config
```

Currently you are passing the headers object as 2nd argument and giving no configuration object (3rd argument), so its natural that your request isn't behaving as expected.

Comment: Perhaps is not a 'post' method (since I don't send any body to the server) but a 'get' method. 
I will try this. Thanks, @Jota.Toledo