# How to add headers to my Angular post request?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

For a school project I need to make a simple login page with Angular. When a login button is clicked I need to add an Authorization header with my post. I created a backend and when I post my Authorization value to that backend with postman it works so nothing wrong with the backend. When I try to post to the same backend with my frontend it doesn't work. What is the best way to add headers to your post? It seems that the opinions are divided. This is my code:

```
export class LoginComponent{
    title = 'Login';
    email = '';
    password = '';
    credentials = '';
    basic = '';
    constructor(private http:HttpClient){

    }

    createAuthorizationHeader(headers:Headers,basic){
        headers.append('Authorization',basic);
    }

    login(event){
        this.email = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("email")).value;
        this.password = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("password")).value;
        this.credentials = this.email + ":" + this.password;
        this.basic = "Basic " + btoa(this.credentials);
        console.log(this.basic);
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization',this.basic);
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers:headers});
        console.log(headers);
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/authenticate',options)
        .subscribe(
            res =>{
                console.log(res);
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        )
    }
}
```

When I run that code I get a 400 status response and the headers are not added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular \[4.3\] Httpclient doesn't send header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286764/angular-4-3-httpclient-doesnt-send-header)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The second argument passed in to [`HttpClient.post`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post) represents the *body* of the request, but you're providing `Headers` here. Use the following to provide the headers correctly:

```
return this.http.post(
    'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/authenticate',
    null,
    options);
```

I've shown `null` in the example for the body, but you probably want that to include the `email` and `password` properties in some form.

You're also mixing `Http` and `HttpClient`. If you're going to use `HttpClient` (which is now the recommended approach), drop `RequestOptions` and `Headers` in favour of [`HttpHeaders`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders). This becomes:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': this.basic });
let options = { headers: headers };
```

The rest of the code stays the same. Your `createAuthorizationHeader` function needs to use and return an instance of `HttpHeaders`. This class is immutable, so `append` returns a *new object* each time it is called. Import `HttpHeaders` from `@angular/common/http`.

Answer (score 4):

This may Help You

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
//post data missing(here you pass email and password)
data= {
"email":email,
"password":password
}
return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/authenticate',data,{ headers: headers})
    .subscribe(
        res =>{
            console.log(res);
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply but already tried this solution and it doesn't work. The headers is still not added.

Comment: your backend should accet 'Content-Type'

Comment: which technology used in backend

Answer (score 0):

```
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set( 'content-type', 
    'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' 
    ); 
    this.http.post( "/api/images", imageInFormData, 
    {headers:this.headers}).subscribe((response)=>{ 
    console.log(response)});
```