# How to send custom HTTP headers to an endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, angular, security, typescript

I'm trying to send an authorization token and my server somehow is not recieving it.

//service.ts

```
...
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
...

 getAllUsers():Observable<User[]>{
 return this.http.get<User[]>(this.backendUrl.getUrl.concat('rest/user/getallusers'),
{headers: new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Authorization', 'Token asdasd')
  .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
});
```

}

//endpoint

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getallusers", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<User> getallusers() {
    return this.userService.getAllUsers();
}
```

//TokenFilter

```
@Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

        String header = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        //Header is null here when I do a request from the browser
        //but with postman it does has a value.
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Token ")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("JWT Token is missing");
        }

        String authenticationToken = header.substring(6);

        JwtAuthenticationToken token = new JwtAuthenticationToken(authenticationToken);
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
    }
```

//CorsConfiguration

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
   registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*")
   .allowedMethods("GET","POST","DELETE");
}
```

But when I do it using POSTMAN it does work.
What am I missing?

[image]

EDIT: Using HttpClient

EDIT: Img to text

```
Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:2030
Origin:http://localhost:4200
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
```

EDIT: Answer, activate CORS in the backend

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

```
http.csrf().disable()
    .cors()  //<-- This one was missing
    .and()
    .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("login").permitAll()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("rest/**").authenticated()
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
    .and()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
    .headers()
    .cacheControl();
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a good occasion for you to try the new `HttpClient` [for which you can find the documentation here](https://angular.io/guide/http#configuring-other-parts-of-the-request)

Simply replace

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http'; // old version
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; // new version
```

With the new client, headers are provided like this

```
http
  .post('/api/items/add', body, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token'),
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have the same results as you can see at the image from chrome dev tools :/

Comment: Well I can't actually (proxy at work, imgur blocked). But I have a good idea of the problem, don't worry ;) just a question for my picture blindness : is your server not finding the token, or is your token not sent by Angular ? (check the `Network` tab of your browser dev tools and see if the request holds the header)

Comment: Is not sent by Angular, I wrote the text showed by image.

Comment: Could you try sending an Authorization header containing the chain `Bearer abcd` Instead of `Token abcd` ?

Comment: I did but i've the same results :(

Comment: I'll try using interceptors following this guide https://medium.com/@milosbejda/adding-authorization-header-to-http-request-in-angular-4-and-5-777b2ce05424

Comment: Well that's your only option, because I can't locate the issue ... Maybe provide a real token to test ?

Comment: Didn't worked , dont know what to try, also did this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286764/angular-4-3-httpclient-doesnt-send-header but didnt worked.
Thank you for you time man :)

Comment: Last thing, did you authorize the Authorization header in your back-end ? Maybe you forgot, and the back-end is not allowing it to be sent ! And no problem, that's what SOF is for :)

Comment: You were right. I had to call ´.cors()´  in the back-end in the WebSecurityConfig file.

Comment: Haha Thank you mate :D