# Angular 5 Interceptor not logging out on failure server call

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

Refrence  : https://gist.github.com/tobbbe/08e01db92c32346b226333a3f952df22

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
           return next.handle(this.addToken(request))
          .pipe(
          catchError((error, ca) => {
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
              switch ((<HttpErrorResponse>error).status) {
                case 401:
                  return this.handle401Error(request, next)
                default:
                  return ErrorObservable.create(error);
              }
            } else {
              return ErrorObservable.create(error);
            }
          })
          )
      }
```

// 401 Error method

```
  handle401Error(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        if (this.isRefreshingToken) {
            this.isRefreshingToken = false;

            // Reset here so that the following requests wait until the token
            // comes back from the refreshToken call.
            this.tokenSubject.next(null);
            const http = this.inj.get(HttpClient);

    let customReq: any;   
    let client_secret= 'temp';
    let basicheader = btoa(client_secret);

       return http.get(AppUtils.REFRESH_TOKEN + localStorage.getItem(AppUtils.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_REFRESH_TOKEN), { new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + basicheader)})  // line 38
              .pipe(
                  switchMap((token: any) => {
                    console.log("token " +JSON.stringify(token));
                    if (token) {
                        localStorage.setItem(AppUtils.STORAGE_TOKEN, token["access_token"]);
                        this.tokenSubject.next(token["access_token"]);
                        return next.handle(this.addToken(req));
                    }

                    console.log("refresh failed");
                    // If we don't get a new token, we are in trouble so logout.
                     this.logoutUser();
                      return EmptyObservable.create();

                }, err => {
                    console.log("error calling add category" + JSON.stringify(err));
                   return EmptyObservable.create();
              }),
                catchError(error => {
                    console.log("error  2" +error);
                    // If there is an exception calling 'refreshToken', bad news so logout.
                     this.logoutUser();
                      return EmptyObservable.create();
                }),
                finalize(() => {
                    this.isRefreshingToken = true;
                })
                )
        } else {
                return this.tokenSubject
                .filter(token => token != null)
                .take(1)
                .switchMap(token => {
                    return next.handle(this.addToken(req));
                });


        }

    }
```

The code is to implement the refresh token, reference https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-4-tutorial-handling-refresh-token-with-new-httpinterceptor/

Having issue like when the line 38 refresh call is made and it returns success then the use case works fine. 
    On 401 error response i.e error response, control is not going to catError or error block as expected. On debug mode cant figure out where the control goes after failure.

What is going wrong with this implementation, how can I make the control to be in error block after 401 error response. Using angular 5 here.

added request interceptor complete code in this https://plnkr.co/edit/7ASmr...
not the working version added just the code.

Comment: I'm wondering how line 38 can ever be successful, as the headers are not properly set?

Comment: @AJT_82 - trust me its successful. :)

Comment: Well with the code we are seeing it shouldn't be :D `HttpHeaders` are immutable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286764/angular-httpclient-doesnt-send-header

Comment: had modified the code but still the issue persist. its not catching 401 error

Answer (score 0):

I have written the following interceptor in order to handle `HttpErrorResponse`, in my case: 401 and 403 status code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

import {AuthService} from '../Services/AuthService';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

      return next.handle(req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>)  => {},
      (err: any) => {

        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {

          if (err.status === 401 || err.status == 403) {
            // Rest of your code
          }
        }
      });
    }
}
```

And added to the `providers` in the `@NgModule` (`app.module.ts`):

```
providers: [
     // Rest of the providers
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
]
```

Note that the `do() operator` is used to handle the error response (`HttpErrorResponse`) and you have to import it as well.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
```