# HttpHeaders not set in Angular 5 HttpClient.post

Tags: angular, angular5

I would like to send a POST-request using the Angular 5 HttpClient.
My code looks like:

```
async download(body: PostZipFileRequest): Promise<any> {
    const post: string = environment.zipFileDownload;
    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
  });
    try {
        return await this.http.post(post, body.Assets, {
            headers: httpHeaders
        }).toPromise();
    } catch (error) {
        this.handleError(error);
    }
}
```

But I get an error of type:
Status Code:415 Unsupported Media Type

[image]

because the Content-Type is 'text/plain' and not 'application/json'.
Why isn't it json like I would expect?
My WebAPI only accepts JSON. If I do a GET-request I don't need any headers. Angular sends "application/json" as Content-Type by default.

Comment: Have you already read through this previous question? [Angular HttpClient doesn't send header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45286764/1260204)

Comment: is that the actual POST request or the preflight request? (request method POST or OPTIONS)

Comment: next question: what is the type of `this.http`? are you using the old Http or the new HttpClient api? Please add the explicit declaration of the mentioned member

Comment: what type is the content of body.Assets ?

Comment: Thank you for the information:

I already copied the post and it doesn't work

Comment: this.http is the new HttpClient from import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: body.Asset is an Array<customType> The payload is correct in the POST

Comment: Try JSON.stringify(body.Assets) in your http call

Comment: JSON.stringify(body.Assets) has the same result: Content-Type:text/plain

Comment: have you tried using interceptors.?

Comment: Can you create minimal example on stackblitz?

Comment: OMG you are right, there is an interceptor for POST-requests. Thanks a lot.