# Angular 5 - Issues when adding headers

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-httpclient

I've this...myservice.service.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ReqLogin, ResLogin, ResList} from '../../interfaces/general';
import { GlobalService} from '../global/global.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

...

list(): Observable<ResList> {
  const url = this.gs.backendServer + this.gs.backend.endpoints.list;
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': this.gs.token
    })
  };
  return this.http.get(url, httpOptions)
    .map(res => <ResList> res)
    .do(dataReceived => console.log(dataReceived));
 }
```

This works fine, the server receive the reader, I receive the data from server, but I receive also this exception:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at eval (http.js:123)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at HttpHeaders.lazyInit (http.js:117)
at HttpHeaders.init (http.js:265)
at HttpHeaders.forEach (http.js:368)
at Observable.eval [as _subscribe] (http.js:2172)
at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:172)
at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:160)
at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:23)
at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:138)
```

if I drop the Http Options, this works perfect.

any clue ?

Comment: There's a bug open for this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22837

Comment: What is the value of `this.gs.token`? Are you sure it isn't empty?

Comment: Are you sure that your `gs.token` is not `undefined`?

Comment: Yes, guys....gs.token not not undefined. I am pretty sure.

Comment: Humm..in fact....This is being called twice for some reason..the 1st time there is no token (undefined)...and yes, you are right, fellas...the undefined value is causing this, according with the but pointed by @Fals

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286764/angular-httpclient-doesnt-send-header/45286959#45286959

Answer (score 0):

Try this using Headers and RequestOptions from @angular/http library.

> ApplicationService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class ApplicationService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  myformPost(id:number, formData : any){

     let header = this.initHeaders();
     let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: header, method: 'post'});
     let body = JSON.stringify(formData);

     return this.http.post(this.myapiUrl, body, options)
                .map(res => {
                    return res.json();
                })
                .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
  }

  private initHeaders(): Headers {
      var headers = new Headers();
      let token = localstorage.getItem(StorageKey.USER_TOKEN);
      if (token !== null) {
         headers.append('Authorization', token);
      }

      headers.append('Pragma', 'no-cache');
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      return headers;
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Observable<any> {
      return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
  }             
}
```

Comment: I was considering this, but I believe that this is about to become deprecated no ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I think the key is your HttpHeaders.

`this.gs.token` maybe is null, so it brings error.

try this:

```
const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Authorization': this.gs.token + ''
})
```

};

Comment: This does not answer the question. Please only post solutions as answers. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer