# Angular 5 missing Content-type in request headers when send to ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api2, angular5

Currently, I'm using Angular 5 to build a website. My website using 0Auth 2.0 to secure a request send to ASP.net Web API 2.0. So, when i try sending a request to get an access token. I use this function :

```
userAuthentication(userName, password) {
let data = "username=" + userName + "&password=" + password + "&grant_type=password&client_id=JCWebApp";
return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + '/login', data,{headers:'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}});
```

}

But web api server return for me response with status code 400. When I check an request header of login request, it like this :

> Accept
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Encoding 
>   gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Language 
>   en-US,en;q=0.5
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers
>   no-auth
>   Access-Control-Request-Method
>   POST
>   Connection
>   keep-alive
>   Host
>   localhost:9810
>   Origin
>   http://localhost:4200
>   User-Agent
>   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0

I researched on the internet, and try many way, all most the answer same as : 
 - [Angular HttpClient doesn't send header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286764/angular-httpclient-doesnt-send-header). But it not working with my situation.

So please help me explain why and how to resolve this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable the CORS in your Web API

download this in nuget **Microsoft.Owin.Cors**

and in  `ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)` located in your Web API

add this line of code `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);`