# HttpClient doesn't send Authorization header [Angular]

Tags: angular, authorization, httpclient

I attempted to send a request with an authorization header using Angular's HttpClient but the header was not sent successfully.

Here's my code.

```
return this.http.get( API_URL + '/validate-email/' + email, this.getToken());
```

And here are my haders:

```
General:
Request URL: http://10.0.2.35:3000/validate-email/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: 10.0.2.35:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade


Request Headers:
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9,gl;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,pt;q=0.6,la;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 10.0.2.35:3000
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/candidate-register
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36



Response Headers: 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 
Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 49
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 21 May 2018 22:19:28 GMT
ETag: W/"31-iT0RTO+b5PSz1cX7BhK1mfQ8R6o"
X-Powered-By: Express
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Hi @Daniela, could you manage to solve this issue. I'm facing same problem and not getting much help around it.

Comment: I could manage to figure it out myself. In my case, it was a custom implementation of  [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor#httpinterceptor) done by another developer which was interfering my request headers. The code in there was trying to pick up Bearer authorization token from a wrong place. Just thought of noting it down here so that someone facing similar issue might want to find out if their code has any custom Interceptor implementation leading to issues they are facing.

Comment: Hi @SameerAwate, actually I had to use an interceptor to make it work and now I use it in every request and works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to a POST request.

```
return this.http.post( API_URL + '/validate-email/' + email, this.getToken());
```

You are including the token in the body, but nothing is done with the body on a GET request.

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/6544475

Comment: I tried with a POST request but still got the same problem.

Comment: We're using node.js

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned anywhere to set `this.getToken()` in the headers. Do the following 
`let requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders = requestHeaders.set('authorization', this.getToken());` 
and then use like
`return this.http.get( API_URL + '/validate-email/' + email, {headers: requestHeaders});`
 
See this for more details [Angular HttpClient doesn't send header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286764/angular-httpclient-doesnt-send-header)

Comment: That's because I set the headers in the method this.getToken() which returns the whole { headers: requestHeaders } object

Comment: can you share `this.getToken()` code? I guess you would be making any mistake there.