# Angular 6 - httpClient passing basic auth in httpOptions

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a service in Angular 6 and I'm trying to change a record but it's saying I'm not authorized.

Right now I have this:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};

  update(id, title, content) {
    const updateData = { id: id, title: title, content: content };
      return this.http.put(`http://myurl/${id}`, updateData, httpOptions);
  }
```

My question is:

How to I add basic authorization to my httpOptions or do I add it direct to the update method?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can add basic authorization by appending it in headers, as below:

```
var headers_object = new HttpHeaders();
headers_object.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers_object.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));

const httpOptions = {
  headers: headers_object
};
```

Comment: This is what i was after but how do I add that to this: const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};

Comment: Getting an error: Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; };

Comment: You have to assign header variable in header parameter. H must be in lowercase. I have updated the solution to avoid the confusion.

Comment: `new Headers();` should be `new HttpHeaders()`

Comment: @PardeepJain It worked in Angular 4. I have updated the answer for Angular 5/6. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, because OP is using v-5/6 as per question details

Comment: Yes, I didn't note that.

Comment: If the code does not work for you, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286764/adding-a-http-header-to-the-angular-httpclient-doesnt-send-the-header-why

Answer (score 9):

Looking at the angular.io documentation, it's pretty straightforward.

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic my-auth-token'
  })
};
```

And you can use the `httpOptions` constant as you did.

For more information: https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers

**PS: This is a method for small or quick apps if you want to build more robust apps, consider using an HTTP interceptor that automatically adds the Authorization header on the fly.**

Comment: Hi friend, I have 2 services for example, authservice to login and userService to get data, after to login i set localstorage and create token and in userService I've trying to get token but without success  const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
  })
}; its don't get token, any idea ?

Answer (score 8):

Just add your token/authorization in the headers like this -

```
let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
              .set('authorization', this.authorizationHeaderValue)
              .set('Content-Type', application/json);
```

> Both have methods such as set and append. set constructs a new body with a new value and append constructs a new body with an appended value

PS: Here I am assuming the variable (this.authorizationHeaderValue) value is included value like `Bearer` or `Basic` or whatever needed, Change it accordingly.

For more read here

- https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-httpclient-get-example#parameters

Comment: it's probably the comma on line 2

Comment: Ohh , that was just a typo mistake. Didn't deserve downvote for this anyways thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: Your Authroization header is wrong. "Authorization" and the value usually has the word "Basic " or "Digest " or "Bearer " in front of the actual token (not the blank space). If this is an OAuth token, then you'd use "Bearer " in front of the authtoken

Comment: @KevinM you are right but I am assuming (As best practice) to be a string inlcuding `Bearer or Basic etc` in the variable named here `this.authToken`. Seems it's self understood

Comment: I wondered if that's what you were implying. But with a variable name of just "authToken" I assumed it was JUST the token itself, not the Authorization header string (I probably would name the variable "authorizationHeaderValue" or something to that effect.

Comment: You are right, Variable name could be better instead of simply `authToken`, Will update the variable name as you suggested. thanks @KevinM

Answer (score 2):

httpClient passing basic auth in httpOptions is different in Angular 6

```
let httpHeaders= new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
httpHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));

const httpOptions = {
  headers: httpHeaders
};

update(id, title, content) {
    const updateData = { id: id, title: title, content: content };
      return this.http.put(`http://myurl/${id}`, updateData, httpOptions);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders(
    {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Basic ` + btoa('user:password'),
    }
  )
};


return this.http.post<any>(
      `apilink`,{},
      httpOptions
    ).pipe(map(res => {
      return res;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

var headers = new HttpHeaders();

var token = localStorage.getItem('token');

headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + token));

const httpOptions = {
  headers: headers
};
```

Comment: localStorage.getItem is to use to get the token value inside to the local storage if you set to the local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Many servers require extra headers for save operations. For example, a server might require an authorization token, or "Content-Type" header to explicitly declare the MIME type of the request body. In your case, you can do basic authorization by following code.

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'; 
const httpOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders({
'Content-Type':  'application/json',
Authorization: 'my-auth-token' })};
```

you can update the authorization header before making the next request

```
httpOptions.headers =  httpOptions.headers.set('Authorization', 'my-new-auth-token');
```