# Angular 8 - httpClient Get method transforms to Options method

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am trying to send Get request to my server(Microsoft 2012). I have already added [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50694988/5736794). But in this is solution my get request transformed to Options method.

```js
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.sas.datamgmt.jobflow.metadata+json; charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization': 'Basic' + btoa('username:password')
  })
};
```

I also added:

```js
    httpOptions.headers.set('username', 'password');
    httpOptions.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    httpOptions.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    httpOptions.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,OPTIONS');
    this.typesOfDBs = this.http.get<Info[]>(this.ROOT_URL, httpOptions);
```

I watched my request and I saw the request is now Options request. How can I handle it and send request as Get method?

Comment: You are mixing request and response headers!

Comment: I also tried without Access-Control-.. statements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used nodejs proxy to solve this question. Nodejs handled it easily. You must send request to nodejs from angular. And to restapi from nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes right, whenever you calls any API from browser it calls OPTIONS for checking that API really callable or server can handle the request with specified criteria.**

If in your case options call gives you success then browser must call actual API with GET method type.

**If not calling with GET method type then there could an issues with headers might be sending more or may less.**

This type of requests works fine with Postman or fiddler or API testing tools but gives issues with browsers.

I would suggest check for headers first if any interceptor try to comment and then test for this API.

Hope so it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a CORS issue, you need to set the headers you specified on the server side, not on the client side making the request