# how to add basic authentication in http request in angular 4

Tags: angular, basic-authentication

I haven't tried anything all i have is http post method, i need to pass the username and password as base authentication to every API i am hitting

```
onSubmit = function(userdata){
     this.tokenkey = localStorage.getItem('logintoken');

  console.log(JSON.stringify(userdata));
this.pass=
{
  "foodid": userdata.foodid,
  "foodname": userdata.foodname,
  "state" : userdata.state,
  "station" : userdata.station,
  "district" : userdata.district,
  "zipcode" : userdata.zipcode,
  "country" : userdata.country,
  "description" : userdata.description,

}
 this.http.post(SERVER_URL+'fooddata/add',this.pass).subscribe((Response) => {
   console.log(Response);
 if(Response.ok === true){
    this.Success();
    this.temp = {};
    this.userdata.reset();
  }
 else this.Error();
})
```

}

Any help on how to pass authentication header in this API ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 6 - httpClient passing basic auth in httpOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694913/angular-6-httpclient-passing-basic-auth-in-httpoptions)

Comment: Hi Richards, So i need to add that Http options in the post method and also would it be useful in angular 4 ?

Comment: Depends. Are you using `HttpClient`, or `Http` to do your `post`? If you are using `Http`, then no, otherwise, yes.

Comment: okay Richards, but the actual output i'm expecting is, once i logged in when i copy the url of any page inside the application and paste it another tab, the page shouldn't come instead it should show authorization error, would this answer gives that output ?

Comment: You should try it and see if that is the behavior you get.

Comment: I've tried but the page is laoding in the another tab and i'm not getting the authorization error on the next tab where I'm pasting the url of the page, any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interceptor that adds the authentication header key-value pair(s) to every request you make. This kind of task is the perfect candidate for Http Interceptors.
Check [this](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) page and [this](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HTTP_INTERCEPTORS) page.

Here is an example:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CustomInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let params = req.params.set('custom-header-name', 'custom-header-value');
        return next.handle(req.clone( { params } ));
    }
}
```

Now, provide this interceptor it in your module where you have imported `HttpClientModule` or any other module:

```
providers: [{provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CustomInterceptor}]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate this with an example please ?

Comment: Added an example

Comment: I have added this code but still i'm getting the error as below

Response {_body: "You cannot access this resource", status: 401, ok: false, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers,

Should i have to do any other thing to get this work done ?

Comment: You will need to check with your server-side on what the expectations are.