# How to append headers to get http in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, http, service, response, angular2-services

I am receiving strange characters from the json file, so i guess the problem with the encoding so i need to **add header** to my http get request in the service
i think something like this

**headers.append('Content-type' , 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');**

and here is my source service code:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from 
'@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class listsService{

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {   }
   //get data from json file
  getList(){
   return this.http.get('../data.json')
  .catch(err => {return "no data";});
 }
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286764/angular-httpclient-doesnt-send-header

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HttpClient doesn't send header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286764/angular-httpclient-doesnt-send-header)