# Unauthorization to protected route when request is made from Angular to Node

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt, authorization, mean-stack

**User.js** (backend)

//profile

```
router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
res.json({
    user: req.user,
})
});
```

**Angular**

**Login Component:**

//onLoginSubmit() is a event Based function

```
onLoginSubmit(){
const user ={
  username:this.username,
  password:this.password
}

this._authService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe(data=>{
  console.log(data);
  this._dataServiceData=data;

  if(this._dataServiceData.success){
    this._authService.storeUserData(this._dataServiceData.token,this._dataServiceData.user);
    this._flahMessage.show('You are now Logged in !',{cssClass:'alert-success',timeout:3000});
    this._router.navigate(['dashboard']);
  }else{
    this._flahMessage.show(this._dataServiceData.msg,{cssClass:'alert-danger',timeout:3000});
    this._router.navigate(['login']);
  }
});
```

}

**On success The return of the data of subscribe is an object:**

*success:true*

*token:"bearer aGh..........Q2rEjhnZ6XjXVKmwNFoiWFjEJk"*

**Then if i am accessing the private Route e.g(profile) than it is unauthorizing it**

**Profile Component**

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
 private _dataService:any={};
 public user={};
  constructor(private _authService:AuthService,
          private _router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
this._authService.getProfile().subscribe(data=>{
  console.log(data);
  this._dataService=data;
  this.user = this._dataService.user;
},err=>{
  console.log(err);
  return false;
})
  }

   }
```

**The AuthService**(Injected to all)

_/**

```
authenticateUser(user){    **called from loginComponent**
   let headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers.append('content-type','application/json');

   return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/users/authenticate',user,{headers:headers})

  }

  getProfile(){          **called from profileComponent**
     let headers = new HttpHeaders();
     this.loadToken();
     headers.append('Authorization',this.token);
     headers.append('content-type','application/json');

     return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/users/profile',{headers:headers})
        }

  loadToken(){
     const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
     this.token=token;
 }


  storeUserData(token,user){
     localStorage.setItem('id_token',token);
     localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(user));

     this.token = token;
     this.user=user;

  }
```

GitHub Repository [link](https://github.com/ShivaChandel/howdy)

While i am accessing the protected Route the error is :

*Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/users/profile: 401 Unauthorized*

Comment: If you look at your headers for the request, you would see that the headers are not set. `HttpHeaders` is immutable and always returns a new instance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286764/angular-httpclient-doesnt-send-header

Comment: Than how can I solve this in getprofile() function

Comment: Look at the accepted answer in the question I linked, it shows you how :)