# Getting a 400 Bad Request error code in Angular 5 POST Call

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, post, postman

I have an ionic app through which i'm calling a rest service with a POST method. I am sending a large string of base64 data to the server. Everything works fine if i send the request through Postman. But, when i send it through the App, it gives me a 400 Bad Request error. 
This is my angular provider code :-

```
 uploadPic(bugImage : any){
    const headers1 = new HttpHeaders();
    headers1.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http.post(this._global.LocalserviceURL + 'ReportaBug', JSON.stringify(bugImage),{headers : headers1}).map(result => result).catch(this.errorHandler);
  }
  errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return Observable.throw(error.message || "Sever Error");
  }
```

and this is how i am using the provider method :-

```
onBasicUpload(e: any) {
    this.imgpov.uploadPic(this.test).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
```

I've looked online and it says to send headers too. I guess i'm sending appropriate headers. How do i get this working?

Comment: 400 that mean your API url incorrect

Comment: I cross checked the url it is fine. it's the same as that i used in Postman

Comment: You can check the difference between your app request and postman request. So you can find out which value is incorrect.

Comment: There are 9 temporary headers auto generated by Postman. That is the only difference i guess.

Comment: Can you check the response message to make sure if you are missing some value in the header?

Comment: How to check that? i have checked the reponse headers in Postman and it looks fine

Comment: Try not using `JSON.stringify`, and send the object as is

Comment: Still the same error!

Comment: Can you show the headers and data that you sent with Postman?

Comment: Headers - http://prntscr.com/o2tgfo

Data - http://prntscr.com/o2tgn1

Comment: can you give a screenshot for your app's request?

Comment: 1 - http://prntscr.com/o2tzsp

2 - http://prntscr.com/o2u06x

Answer (score 1):

I find out the root cause should be the Content-type haven't been updated in your request header.

Try to use
const headers1 = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
like [Angular HttpClient doesn't send header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286764/angular-httpclient-doesnt-send-header)
[image]

Comment: I tried it, now the Content-Type has changed to application/json but i'm still getting the same error
Screenshot - http://prntscr.com/o2v9nf

Comment: can you give me a screenshot about the error response to check if there is any information?.

Comment: Or if it's body data issue instead of header issue? Because I saw there was no "data:image/png;base64" before your postman request

Answer (score 0):

You need to see the 'content-type headers'

```
headers: new HttpHeaders( {
      **'Content-Type': 'application/json'**,
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token
    } )
```

> Or

```
headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

> So based on Requested content-type you need to add those headers.

Comment: I have already added 'Content-Type': 'application/json' header into my request.

Comment: To make sure on URL, can you please check your query params (type checks )properties with Postman properties?

Comment: They are all blank.

Comment: If you could share the screenshot of postman request & result and app request & respone, will help us to understand the problem further.

Comment: Postman Headers - https://prnt.sc/o2tgfo Postman Body - https://prnt.sc/o2tgn1

App request 1 -  https://prnt.sc/o2tzsp App request 2 - https://prnt.sc/o2u06x

Comment: In Request headers, it should be 'Content-Type': application/json.