# Adding headers seems to fail based on the response from server in Angular HttpClient while working in Postman

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers, angular9, angular-httpclient

When I check a call in Postman, using the single header *INFO* added with value of *blopp*, I get the result as expected (it's JWT containing the value passed in as *sub*, a bit dummy service, agreed on that). When I deactivate the header, I'm getting a token with an empty *sub*. This is the predicted behavior.

I'm executing the following script. When I check the call's result, I see a token recieved containing an empty *sub*, desipte sending in the headers.

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "INFO": "blopp"
});
const options = { headers };

this.http.get<{ token: string }>(url, options)
  .subscribe(next =>  console.log(next.token));
```

My diagnostic tells me that I somehow fail to pass in the headers, because the behavior aligns with the result of deactivating the headers in Postman (as well as executing the URL with no headers from the browser).

How should I pass the value to be a part of the invokation as a header? Alternatively, if I'm already doing it the right way, how can I diagnose it further without access to the backend (since it works in Postman, I'm sure it's something on my end).

I've made sure to respect the immutability and tested all the approaches listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45286959/1525840) and I try to follow what [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers) tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I'm using [proxy facility](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) for Angular to emulate work-around the CORS issue. Apparently, they don't mention all the options that should be specified in the *proxy.config.json* file. And missing `changeOrigin: true`, causes the headers to fall off, even if they are explicitly hardcoded in the very same config file!

All credit to [this blog](https://medium.com/ngconf/use-proxy-to-easily-call-your-apis-during-development-2b30849939b7) actually listing that setting.