# laravel and angular routes overlapping and redirect to 404

Tags: angular, laravel, angular-routing, laravel-routing

I have an angular project which is my root website and having a Laravel project in the `backend` folder in `public_html`. I have two types of routes, `/backend/api/**` is my api routes which I want to redirect to /404 in angular project when user want to access directly in the browser but want to access via `httpclient` module in angular and I have `/backend/admin/**` which is my admin routes and I want to stay untouched and can be accessed via the browser. My problem is the `**` route in the angular overlap all the laravel routes and redirects to /404. what is the best solution. should I change .htaccess file or what? would you please help me?

Comment: you can add custom header to angular `httpClient` then based on server (laravel can react)

Comment: the request does not get to laravel controller due to ** route in angular

Comment: means your not able to call api ?

Comment: strangely i can call api but when i load that api route in browser it redirects to 404

Comment: oh then what is wrong with it ?

Comment: even my admin routes redirect to 404. /backend/admin

Comment: oh then remove that redirection and use custom header to redirect only api routes to angular

Comment: would you please give me an example how is that work

Answer (score 0):

i don't know about angular so i took ref from this
[Adding a HTTP header to the Angular HttpClient doesn't send the header, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286764/adding-a-http-header-to-the-angular-httpclient-doesnt-send-the-header-why)

in angular

```js
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('from', 'api');
```

then create a middleware

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if($request->header('from') != 'api'){
        return redirect('/'); // replace this with your url
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

> **NOTE** this is not exact solution but it is an idea

Comment: that is ok for api call and admin call but how about the other routes ... i mean the other non angular routes will not redirect to 404 ... since i need to remove 404 route from angular then doing that

Comment: @ArazShamsaddinlouy you just need to apply this middleware