# Getting a 401 status code when performing POST request in Angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot, spring-security, http-status-code-401

I have a Spring Boot backend with security enabled, and I'm trying to POST request on the http://localhost:4200/snippetcollection endpoint.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // CORS configuration
    // CSRF configuration
    // route security w/ role configurations
    http.cors().configurationSource(new CorsConfigurationSource() {

        @Override
        public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
            CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
            config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
            config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
            config.setAllowCredentials(true);
            config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
            config.setMaxAge(3600L);
            return config;
        }

    }).and().csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/register", "/snippetcollection")
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/snippetcollection").hasAnyRole(Role.FREE_USER.name(), Role.PRO_USER.name())
            .antMatchers("/dashboard").hasAnyRole(Role.FREE_USER.name(), Role.PRO_USER.name())
            .antMatchers("/profile").hasAnyRole(Role.FREE_USER.name(), Role.PRO_USER.name())
            .antMatchers("/tags").hasAnyRole(Role.FREE_USER.name(), Role.PRO_USER.name())
            .antMatchers("/shared").hasRole(Role.PRO_USER.name())
            .antMatchers("/settings").hasAnyRole(Role.FREE_USER.name(), Role.PRO_USER.name())
            .antMatchers("/user").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/home", "/documentation", "/pricing", "/register", "/share", "/login").permitAll()
            .and().httpBasic()
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    
    return http.build();
}

// bcrypt encoder
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

}

In Postman, I have set the Authorization to Basic Auth with my credentials and I'm getting 201 CREATED SUCCESS response from the http://localhost:4200/snippetcollection endpoint. But In Angular code I'm getting a 401 status code & error.
[POSTMAN SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86cAs.png) AND [POSTMAN HEADERS SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIiPx.png)

**Angular code**

HTTP interceptor

```
   @Injectable()
   export class AjaxhttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
   // initialize a user model obj
   user = new User();

   // inject the router obj
   constructor(private router: Router) {}

   // override the intercept method
   intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
   // this http header is used to add authorization details
   let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

// map userdetails to user model if it already exists in the session storage
if (sessionStorage.getItem('userdetails')) {
  this.user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('userdetails')!);
}

// append when user is trying to login
if (this.user && this.user.password && this.user.email) {
  httpHeaders = httpHeaders.append(
    'Authorization',
    'Basic ' + window.btoa(this.user.email + ':' + this.user.password)
  );
}

let xsrf = sessionStorage.getItem('XSRF-TOKEN');
if (xsrf) {
  httpHeaders = httpHeaders.append('X-XSRF-TOKEN', xsrf);
}

httpHeaders = httpHeaders.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
const xhr = req.clone({
  headers: httpHeaders,
});

return next.handle(xhr).pipe(
  tap((err: any) => {
    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      if (err.status !== 401) {
        return;
      }
      // if success, navigate to user dashboard
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    }
  })
);
  }
  }
```

Service

```
export class DashboardService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

createSnippetCollection(snippetcollection: SnippetCollection) {
   return this.http.post(
     environment.rooturl + '/snippetcollection',
     snippetcollection,
     { observe: 'response', withCredentials: true }
    );
 }
}
```

Some component using the Service

```
this.dashboardService
    .createSnippetCollection({
      title: 'noasdsadasde export link',
      description: 'Cerasdasdvus Lorem ipsom dolor sadasdamet',
      programmingLanguage: 'nasdasdde',
    })
    .subscribe((responseData) => {
      console.log(responseData);
    });
```

Comment: Can you show the headers you're sending in Postman?

Comment: @jquijano here it is https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIiPx.png

Comment: Please see the following answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45286959/5100770), I think your append won't work since the instances of the new HttpHeader class are ```immutable``` objects.